# Primitive Dirichlet Character

Tags: number-theory, characters

Let $\chi$ be the trivial Dirichlet character mod $N$. What is the primitive Dirichlet character associated to $\chi$? Is it just the character on $\mathbb{Z}$ that sends all integers to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, exactly. :)

Here are more characters to meet the minimum.

Comment: ...and its Dirichlet generating function is that famous function of Riemann...

Comment: "more characters..." - was that a pun?

Comment: "That would be telling..."

Comment: @Gerry ... to trigger the software... :)

Comment: Maaaaan.... this software situation is not ... useful... Sorry if my responses are [obstructed-by] ...